# Get model instance in custom request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a models with custom rules of validation, In every model I have variable $rules:

```
public static $rules = [...];
```

https://medium.com/@konafets/a-better-place-for-your-validation-rules-in-laravel-f5e3f5b7cc

I want use these rules in custom request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ModelRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check() ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return static::$rules;  
    }
}
```

I get error:

```
Access to undeclared static property: App\Http\Requests\ModelRequest::$rules
```

In controller:

```
public function store(ModelRequest $request)
{
    ...
}
```

This is globally. I need get instance of model, but how?

Comment: In which class did you define the static `$rules` property?

Comment: Where did you define this `$rules` property?

Comment: @Jerodev in model

Comment: Which model, cause it doesn't seem to be in `ModelRequest` class.

Comment: @mega6382 in model. Please see updated question

Comment: @mega6382 This is globall Request. I have multiple models with $rules. I don't want create custom request for every model. Why? If I can do this in one custom request.

Comment: Well, then this is invalid way of accessing them `static::$rules`, you should be using something like `ModelClass::$rules` instead

Comment: @mega6382 how I can get this model from request? :) I can manually do this, but I have more 10 models..

Answer (score 0):

If you've put the **$rules** variable in your model you can't access it like this, because **static** refers to the class you are currently in. 
Try this out:

> **Notice:** I assume that your models are under the **App** name space

```
   // In your model class
   class YourModel extends Model{

     const RULES=[];

   }

   //Then in your request class
  class ModelRequest extends FormRequest 
  {
    public function rules()
    {
      return App\YourModel::RULES;  
    }
  }
```